# how to make div classes and its images responsive

Tags: html, css

How to make this slider responsive in all devices .
Waht should i use in css to make it responsive.
as its not going responsive after adding three more div classes.
Thank you

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; padding-top: 0px; width: 1100px; height: 530px; left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">


    <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-11">
                    <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1040px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
                        <!-- Loading Screen -->
                        <div class="container">
                            <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1040px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
                                <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" data-u="image" style="padding-top: 26px;"src="images/birch-899553_1920.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" data-u="image" style="padding-top: 26px;" src="images/house-949265_1920.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" data-u="image"  style="padding-top: 26px;" src="images/nature-958406_1920.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" data-u="image" style="padding-top: 26px;" src="images/birch-112829_1920.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" data-u="image" style="padding-top: 26px;" src="images/park-454416_1920.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" data-u="image"  style="padding-top: 26px;"src="images/columbine-981541_1920.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                                    <img  class="img-rounded img-responsive" data-u="image" style="padding-top: 26px;" src="images/garden-705485_1920.jpg" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
                        <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="bottom:16px;right:16px;">
                            <div data-u="prototype" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
                        <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora02l" style="top:0px;left:8px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
                        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora02r" style="top:0px;right:8px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you .

Comment: an image slider on mobile is a bad idea IMHO as it is too heavy to load the scripts and all of the images, it is better to just have 1 picture for mobile.

Comment: this is my main slider of website.. any tricks to make it responsive @CarolMcKay

Comment: Do not use fix widhts. You can set it with max-width and use 100% for the normal width.

Comment: Yeah or a max-width:100%; if you want to keep your numbers @KNugal